# How to update an existing Alarm in ScheduledActionService on Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, alarm, scheduledactionservice

In my app, I have an `Alarm` which is scheduled to start at 8:00am (`BeginTime`). The problem I am facing is that I am not sure what's the most appropriate way to update its `BeginTime`.

I tried to locate the `Alarm` in the `ScheduledActionService` and then updated it from there. Unfortunately it didn't seem to work, the `Alarm` never gets triggered.

```
        var schedule = ScheduledActionService.Find(alarmModel.Name);

        if (schedule != null)
        {
            var alarm = (Alarm)schedule;

            if (alarm.BeginTime != alarmModel.BeginTime)
            {
                alarm.BeginTime = alarmModel.BeginTime;
            }
        }
```

If I removed it from the `ScheduledActionService` and then add a new one then it worked.

But this looks ugly though... Is this the only way I can 'update' an `Alarm`???!

Thanks,

Xin

Comment: Add an extension method called Update that Finds and Removes? A while back when I was using ScheduledActionService I simply had my code Find & Remove.

Comment: @willmel Yeah that's what I am doing atm, which will work, but I don't like the idea that you have to remove it and add a new one...

Comment: Yeah, it's a little less than ideal- but hey, that's the benefit of extension methods and abstraction! code it once, and never deal with it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The correct approach must be to call [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.scheduledactionservice.replace%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)() .

```
   var schedule = ScheduledActionService.Find(alarmModel.Name);

    if (schedule != null)
    {
        var alarm = (Alarm)schedule;

        if (alarm.BeginTime != alarmModel.BeginTime)
        {
            alarm.BeginTime = alarmModel.BeginTime;
            ScheduledActionService.Replace(alarm);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I actually tried the`Replace` function before, and it didn't work. I think it is a bug. See this post, http://blogs.developpeur.org/kookiz/archive/2011/10/22/wp7-scheduledactionservice-replace-bug-or-documentation-error.aspx Still, replacing the entire object with another doesn't seem to be an elegant solution to me.

Comment: It worked, Xin. What the author of the post intended to say is, the function does NOT depend on Name as MSDN states. Instead, the method is based on an Guid called "m_id". Still, you can use it to update your BeginTime.

Comment: Okay, now I get it. Thanks for this.